# URL_STRING não se preenche corretametne

Tags: android, string, web-service, url

Estou com um problema na classe de consumo do meu WebService rest. No projeto existem apenas duas classes, a MainActivity está funcionando corretamente, mas a classe de consumo (ConsumoWS) não está entendendo meu método para preencher a url/uri que é enviado ao WS.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.testedosbotoes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ConsomeWS post;
String nome;
String enderecoOI = "El/oi";
String enderecoOO = "El/oo";
static String enderecoGO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button bt09 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_btnovehoras);
        Button bt10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_btdezhoras);



        bt09.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                MainActivity.setendereco(enderecoOI);


                  post=new ConsomeWS();
                  post.execute();
                nome = new String (post.getnome());
                if (nome !=null) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "começou", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        

                }

            }

        });

        bt10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MainActivity.setendereco(enderecoOO);
                post=new ConsomeWS();
                post.execute();
                nome = new String (post.getnome());
                if (nome !=null) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nao começou", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        };
        });


    }

    public static void setendereco (String endereco){

        enderecoGO = endereco;

    }

    public static String getendereco() {


        return enderecoGO;
    }

}
```

---

ConsomeWS:

```
package com.example.testedosbotoes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class ConsomeWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{


    static String endereco;
    private static final String URL_STRING = "http://192.168.1.5:8080/"+endereco;

    String nome;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        endereco = MainActivity.getendereco();

                Log.i("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh", "solicitar endereco" + endereco);

        try {

            String resultado = consultaServidor();

            return interpretaresultado(resultado);





        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }



        private String consultaServidor() throws IOException {

            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                Log.i("IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII", "solicitar endereco" + URL_STRING);

                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL_STRING);

                Log.i("JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ", "solicitar endereco" + URL_STRING);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(webs);
                char[] buffer = new char[3999];
                reader.read(buffer);

                return new String(buffer);


                } finally {

                    if (is !=null){

                        is.close();
                    }

                }
        }

            private String interpretaresultado(String resultado) throws JSONException {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultado);

                return object.getString("resposta");

        }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



                setNome(result);

            }

            public void setNome(String result) {

                this.nome = result;

            }

            public String getnome(){

                return this.nome;
            }

}
```

---

Erro do logcat:

```
08-09 13:47:32.052: D/gralloc_goldfish(2570): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-09 13:47:58.742: D/AndroidRuntime(2570): Shutting down VM
08-09 13:47:58.742: W/dalvikvm(2570): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a87ba8)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570): Process: com.example.testedosbotoes, PID: 2570
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:443)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at com.example.testedosbotoes.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-09 13:47:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2570):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 13:47:58.762: I/hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh(2570): solicitar enderecoEl/oi
08-09 13:47:58.762: I/IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII(2570): solicitar enderecohttp://192.168.1.5:8080/null
08-09 13:47:59.112: I/JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ(2570): solicitar enderecohttp://192.168.1.5:8080/null
08-09 13:48:00.582: I/Process(2570): Sending signal. PID: 2570 SIG: 9
```

---

Observem que o logcat aponta que a URL_STRING está incompleta T_T (192.168.1.5:8080/null) quando deveria constar (192.168.1.5:8080/El/oi).

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido!

Fiz a seguinte alteração na Classe, e funcionou \o/:

```
public class ConsomeWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

private static final String URL_STRING = "http://192.168.1.5:8080/"+endereco(); 

String nome;

private static String endereco() {
    String ender;
    ender = MainActivity.getendereco();
    Log.i("IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII", "e ai" + ender);
    return ender;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {       

    try {

        String resultado = consultaServidor();          
        return interpretaresultado(resultado);      

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}

    private String consultaServidor() throws IOException {

        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL_STRING);

            Log.i("JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ", "solicitar endereco" + URL_STRING);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(webs);
            char[] buffer = new char[3999];
            reader.read(buffer);

            return new String(buffer);

            } finally {

                if (is !=null){

                    is.close();
                }

            }
    }

        private String interpretaresultado(String resultado) throws JSONException {

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultado);

            return object.getString("resposta");

    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            setNome(result);

        }

        public void setNome(String result) {

            this.nome = result;

        }

        public String getnome(){

            return this.nome;
        }

}
```

---

```
Logcat: 08-10 11:28:25.476: I/JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ(995): solicitar enderecohttp://192.168.1.5:8080/El/oi
```

XD.
Só que agora tem outro erro T_T